# How to merge two dictionaries but on duplicate keys combine the values in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries each with the same structure.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictA
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictB
```

I want to merge the two dictionaries in such a way that for each key if it exists in both dictA and dictB I combine the the two lists together and use that as the value otherwise it just gets included. eg:

```
("wow", {0,0,0})
("key", {1,2,3}) in A

("qwerty", {4,0,4})
("key", {4,5,6}) in B
```

becomes

```
("wow", {0,0,0})
("qwerty", {4,0,4})
("key", {1,2,3,4,5,6})
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: One algorithm could be: go through each entry in `dictA`, check if `dictB` has an entry with the same key. If not, just take the `dictA` entry otherwise join both entries (`listA.Concat(listB).ToList()`). Then go through each entry in `dictB`, check if `dictA` has an entry with the same key. If not, just take the `dictB` entry, otherwise ignore it, because it was already handled in going through `dictA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first merge your dictionaries in a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>>` by combining them with [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1). We do this because some keys may not exist in both dictionaries, and we want them included in the final merged result.

We can then group the keys with [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netcore-3.1), then create a final merged `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` with [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1), ensuring that the inner grouped lists are flattened with [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1).

```
var dictA = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
{
    { "wow", new List<int>{0,0,0} },
    { "key", new List<int>{1,2,3} }
};

var dictB = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
{
    { "querty", new List<int>{4,0,4} },
    { "key", new List<int>{4,5,6} }
};

var merged = dictA
    .Concat(dictB)
    .ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.SelectMany(x => x).ToList());

foreach (var kvp in merged)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} -> {"{ " + string.Join(", ", kvp.Value) + " }"}");
}
```

Output:

```
wow -> { 0, 0, 0 }
key -> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
querty -> { 4, 0, 4 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with linq but it's simple to do with just a couple foreach loops.

```
var dictA = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
{
    { "wow", new List<int>{0,0,0} },
    { "key", new List<int>{1,2,3} }
};
var dictB = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
{
    { "querty", new List<int>{4,0,4} },
    { "key", new List<int>{4,5,6} }
};

var merged = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

foreach(var kvp in dictA)
{
    merged.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

    if(dictB.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var inB))
    {
        kvp.Value.AddRange(inB);
        dictB.Remove(kvp.Key);
    }
}

foreach (var kvp in dictB)
    merged.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```